# Is the example of the descriptor protocol in the Python 3.6 documentation incorrect?

Tags: python, python-3.6, descriptor

I am new to Python and looking through its documentation I encountered the following example of the descriptor protocol that in my opinion is incorrect. .

It looks like

```
class IntField:
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise ValueError(f'expecting integer in {self.name}')
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

    # this is the new initializer:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

class Model:
    int_field = IntField()
```

Here are my considerations.

The attribute `int_field` is a class-wide attribute is not it?

So `owner.__dict__` will have such a key. However in the method `__get__` there is used `instance.__dict__` that does not have that key. So from the point of view of using the method the method does not deal with the class-wide attribute but deals with an instance-wide attribute.

On the other hand, the method `__set__` also does not deal with the class-wide attribute but creates an instance-wide attribute because there is used

```
instance.__dict__[self.name] = value
```

So it looks like each instance of the class creates its own instance-wide attribute. Moreover a reference to the class even is not passed to the method.

Am I right or do I have missed something that I do not know yet?

To make my considerations more clear the example logically is equivalent to the following

```
class MyClass:
    int_field = 10

instance_of = MyClass();

instance_of.__dict__["int_field"] = 20

print( MyClass.int_field )
print( instance_of.int_field )
```

The program output is

```
10
20
```

The instance attribute `int_field` has nothing common with the class-wide attribute `int_field` except its name.

The same is true for the example from the documentation. Intuitively one can expect that it is the class-wide attribute that is attached to the descriptor. However it is not true. The descriptor just borrows the name of the class-wide attribute. On the other hand, a class-wide attribute can indeed be attached to a descriptor.

So the example from the documentation in my opinion just confuses readers.

Comment: Setting an instance attribute is the whole point. That is what it is supposed to do.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the descriptor protocol.  Descriptors hijack the dot in attribute access.  It doesn't really help much to think of descriptors as either class attributes or instance attributes.

Comment: Yeah, at this level, the exact definition of "attribute" becomes important, and it's probably better to think in terms of underlying storage and attribute *access*, rather than attributes being a concrete thing you can point to.

Comment: @wim May I use MyClass.attribute for a class-wide attribute instead of instance.attribute? So what do not I understand?

Comment: I'm not sure what you think is *incorrect* about the example in the docs...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In the example there is declared a class-wide attribute. However the descriptor deals with instance-wide attributes. It has nothing common with the class-wide attribute except its name.

Comment: Well, first, nothing is "declared." But anyway, yes *the descriptor object itself is an attribute that belongs to the class*, that manages access to *other attributes* that belong to instances of that class, or perhaps even "class attributes". Again, *what do you think is "wrong"* here?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I already said what is wrong. What is unclear? Do you see a difference between Myclass.attribute and instance_of_MyVlass.attribute?

Comment: No, you haven't stated anything "wrong", you've merely described how descriptors work...

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yes, I see the difference, and your descriptor handles each of those cases. The example deals with a descriptor that manages an instance attribute. Again, **what is wrong**? The example works correctly.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga All is clear written in my question. I am regret that you do not understand what is written.

Comment: I understand perfectly. You seem to think that it is *wrong* that the descriptor is an attribute that belongs to a class, but that manages instance attributes. There is nothing "wrong" about this. Or at least, you haven't explained why that is "wrong".

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga One more it does not work correctly because it has nothing common with the class-wide attribute.

Comment: You keep repeating "it does not work correctly", but you never describe what you mean by that. "It had nothing in common with the class-wide attribute", huh? So what? The class-attribute is the *descriptor object itself*, the descriptor object manages an *instance attribute*. I just ran the code and it is working 100% correctly. Perhaps if you wrote some code that *demonstrated incorrect behavior* then this question would become more fruitful.

Comment: Aha, but the example **is not equivalent to that**. Run the example, you'll see that `MyClass.int_field` throws an error. EDIT or rather, `Model.int_field`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes an error will occur. This confirms that the descriptor does not deal with the class-wide attribute. It seems you have understood this at last.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yes, but that descriptor is *not designed to*. That isn't "wrong". This is simply a descriptor that manages instance attributes. The vast majority of user-defined descriptors do this, indeed, the built-in `property` decorator lets you do this with less boilerplate. But *descriptors always belong to the class*. Again, there is nothing "wrong" here. You've simply described how descriptors work.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga All instances shall share class-wide attributes. So I would expect looking the example that it is the class-wide attribute that is attached to the descriptor. However the descriptor does not deal with the shared attribute. It deals with each instance attribute of the class. It is not the same.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Look, you've got a lot of really firm preconceptions about how attributes work in Python, but those preconceptions are simply wrong when dealing with descriptors or anything else that overrides normal attribute lookup.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Why did you decide that this descriptor manages instance attributes? It is attached to the class-wide attribute. So  the reader can expect that it is the class-wide attribute that will be calculated.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow because I understand the descriptor protocol, and that descriptors *belong to a class* **regardless** of the attributes they manage. This is exactly the same as methods that behave non-statically, they *belong to the class*, but they *operate on instances*. You seem to be confusing your own erroneous ideas of how Python *should work*, with how Python *actually does work*. When you say "So the reader can expect that it is the class-wide attribute that will be calculated" that is merely *your presupposition*, which comes from working with languages that are not Python.

Answer (score 3):

The example is fine.

> However in the method `__get__` there is used `instance.__dict__` that does not have that key.

There *will* be such a key once you actually set `instance.int_field`, which will invoke the property setter and assign the key.

> On the other hand, the method `__set__` also does not deal with the class-wide attribute but creates an instance-wide attribute

The setter isn't supposed to create a class attribute. It assigns to the instance dict key the getter is looking for.

Comment: I see nothing fine because there are mixing two kinds of attributes. In my opinion the example is contradictory and only confuses readers.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: At this level, "class attribute" and "instance attribute" are messy concepts. There is an `'int_field'` key in `Model.__dict__` referring to an instance of `IntField`. This does not mean that `int_field` is a class attribute; it means that the `IntField` instance will handle attribute access for the `int_field` attribute name on `IntField`, its subclasses, and its instances.

Comment: The example is not self-contradictory. It may contradict some simplified, incomplete models of Python attribute access, but it does not contradict itself or the complete attribute access mechanics.

Comment: I can not agree. Using the descriptor methods you can achieve that all instances will access a class-wide attribute and neither Instance will create its own attribute.  It is the example that is wrong.

Comment: "Using the descriptor methods you can achieve that all instances will access a class-wide attribute and neither Instance will create its own attribute" - well, you *could* do that, but it'd be kind of weird, and it wouldn't make other uses wrong. I can stuff a banana up my nose, but that doesn't mean doing other things with bananas is wrong.

Comment: (Well, weird for a data descriptor, anyway. Plenty of non-data descriptors don't store anything on the instance.)

Answer (score 2):

I think I can see what piece of the puzzle you're missing here: The `self` in the `__get__` *is* the descriptor! That's why we set state in the `instance.__dict__`. It is not usual to set the state on self (i.e. on the descriptor), because then each instance of `Model` would be sharing that state.

There is nothing contradictory in the example, but the names used here are somewhat ambiguous.  Perhaps some renaming will help:

```
class IntField:
    def __get__(self, obj, type_):
        # typically: self is an IntField(), obj is a Model(), type_ is Model
        return obj.__dict__[self.the_internal_name]

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise ValueError(f'expecting integer, but received {type(value)}')
        obj.__dict__[self.the_internal_name] = value

    def __set_name__(self, type_, name):
        # this is called at class definition time, i.e. descriptor init time
        self.the_internal_name = name + '_internal'

class Model:
    int_field = IntField()
```

I've also disambiguated the name on the class (`'int_field'`), the name on the descriptor (`'the_internal_name'`) and the name which gets used in the instance's dict (`'int_field_internal'`).

All the `self` in the code above refer to the *descriptor instance*.  And there is *one* descriptor instance that handles attribute access for all instances of `Model`.  The `type_` (what the docs called `owner`) will be `Model`.  The `obj` will be an instance, `Model()`.

There is also an important piece of code that is missing from the example.  It's usual to put some logic into the `__get__`, in order to allow access to the descriptor object itself:

```
def __get__(self, obj, type_=None):
    print(f'Descriptor was accessed with obj {obj} and type_ {type_}')
    if obj is None:
        # the descriptor was invoked on the class instead of an instance
        # returning self here allows 'class attribute' access!
        return self  
    return obj.__dict__[self.the_internal_name]
```

Let's try it out:

```
>>> m = Model()
>>> m.__dict__
{}
>>> m.int_field = 123
>>> m.__dict__
{'int_field_internal': 123}
>>> m.int_field
Descriptor was accessed with obj <__main__.Model object at 0x7fffe8186080> and type_ <class '__main__.Model'>
123
>>> Model.int_field
Descriptor was accessed with obj None and type_ <class '__main__.Model'>
<__main__.IntField at 0x7fffe8174748>
>>> Model.int_field.__dict__
Descriptor was accessed with obj None and type_ <class '__main__.Model'>
{'the_internal_name': 'int_field_internal'}
```

So, as you can see, the descriptor instance (which you may think of as a class attribute, if you want) handles attribute access for the `int_field` name on `Model` instances and also on `Model` itself.  When accessed on an instance, it gets/sets state in the `int_field_internal` name on the instance.  Since I've disambiguated the names, you could also access `m.int_field_internal` as a normal attribute get/set that same value bypassing the descriptor, if you wanted to (it's common practice for properties to do this, using an internal `_name`).

In general usage, we use the same name in the instance dict as the descriptor's "label" for it, because... why not?  This *shadows* the normal attribute access to the instance name, because the descriptor protocol has priority.  But you could still bypass the descriptor as shown below:

```
print(m.int_field)  # this access goes through the descriptor object
print(m.__dict__['int_field'])  # this is 'raw' access
```

See if you can guess what `Model.int_field.the_internal_name` will return, why, and try it out!  Then try creating a new model like this:

```
class Model2:
    field_one = IntField()
    field_two = IntField()
```

And then you will see how `__set_name__` is used.  Descriptors allow you to make whatever you want happen during regular attribute access (be it get, set, or delete...).  You can use it manage state on the class, the instance, or the descriptor itself - as you want - and that's why it can be confusing to explain, but that's also where the power and flexibility of this feature comes from.