# Why does this class descriptor __get__ method return self?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-descriptors

I am working through the *O Reilley Python Cookbook* and I have a question about the following code:

```
class Typed:
    def __init__(self, name, expected_type):
        self.name = name
        self.expected_type = expected_type

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        else:
            return instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, self.expected_type):
            raise TypeError('Expected ' + str(self.expected_type))
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        del instance.__dict__[self.name]

# Class decorator that applies it to selected attributes
def typeassert(**kwargs):
    def decorate(cls):
        for name, expected_type in kwargs.items():
            # Attach a Typed descriptor to the class
            setattr(cls, name, Typed(name, expected_type))
        return cls
    return decorate

# Example use
@typeassert(name=str, shares=int, price=float)
class Stock:
    def __init__(self, name, shares, price):
        self.name = name
        self.shares = shares
        self.price = price

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Stock('ACME', 100, 490.1)
    print(s.name, s.shares, s.price)
    s.shares = 50
    try:
        s.shares = 'a lot'
    except TypeError as e:
        print(e)
```

Im confused about the part:

```
def __get__(self, instance, cls):
    if instance is None:
        return self
    else:
        return instance.__dict__[self.name]
```

if instance is not set (ie None) then it says return 'self', given that self represents the class descriptor what exactly is returned?

Comment: Related:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46611559/674039

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it returns the descriptor instance.

The second argument (the first after `self`) for `__get__` is either the instance on which the descriptor is looked up - or `None` if it's looked up on the class.

So in the given case it returns the descriptor in case you look up the descriptor on the class.

Just to illustrate that:

```
class Descriptor:
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return 10

class Test:
    test = Descriptor()


>>> Test.test
<__main__.Descriptor at 0x2769b7d44c8>

>>> Test.__dict__['test']
<__main__.Descriptor at 0x2769b7d44c8>
```

Now, if it didn't use `return self` there it would look like this:

```
class Descriptor:
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return 10

class Test:
    test = Descriptor()


>>> Test.test
10

>>> Test.__dict__['test']
<__main__.Descriptor at 0x2769b7de208>
```

The reason this `return self` is often done is because it allows to get the descriptor instance without having to search in `__dict__` (potentially in all superclasses). In most cases it simply makes no sense to do anything when the property is looked up on the class, so returning the instance is a good idea.

It's also what the built-in `property` does (and also the function-descriptor):

```
class A:
    @property
    def testproperty(self):
        return 10

    def testmethod(self):
        return 10

>>> A.testproperty
<property at 0x2769b7db9a8>
>>> A.testproperty.__get__(None, A)
<property at 0x2769b7db9a8>

>>> A.testmethod
<function __main__.A.testmethod(self)>
>>> A.testmethod.__get__(None, A)
<function __main__.A.testmethod(self)>
```

---

In those cases where something meaningful should happen when the attribute is looked up on the class (for example the built-in `staticmethod` and `classmethod` descriptors) then that's of course different and `self` should not be returned there!

Answer (score 1):

> then it says return 'self', given that self represents the class
>   descriptor what exactly is returned?

You've just answered your own question: it returns the descriptor object itself.

So when the descriptor is accessed on the class, `instance` will be `None`, and in this case it just returns the descriptor. Consider the example of `property` re-implemented in Python from the Descriptor HOWTO:

```
In [5]: class Property(object):
   ...:     "Emulate PyProperty_Type() in Objects/descrobject.c"
   ...:
   ...:     def __init__(self, fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None):
   ...:         self.fget = fget
   ...:         self.fset = fset
   ...:         self.fdel = fdel
   ...:         if doc is None and fget is not None:
   ...:             doc = fget.__doc__
   ...:         self.__doc__ = doc
   ...:
   ...:     def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
   ...:         if obj is None:
   ...:             print('obj is None in Property.__get__')
   ...:             return self
   ...:         if self.fget is None:
   ...:             raise AttributeError("unreadable attribute")
   ...:         return self.fget(obj)
   ...:
   ...:     def __set__(self, obj, value):
   ...:         if self.fset is None:
   ...:             raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
   ...:         self.fset(obj, value)
   ...:
   ...:     def __delete__(self, obj):
   ...:         if self.fdel is None:
   ...:             raise AttributeError("can't delete attribute")
   ...:         self.fdel(obj)
   ...:
   ...:     def getter(self, fget):
   ...:         return type(self)(fget, self.fset, self.fdel, self.__doc__)
   ...:
   ...:     def setter(self, fset):
   ...:         return type(self)(self.fget, fset, self.fdel, self.__doc__)
   ...:
   ...:     def deleter(self, fdel):
   ...:         return type(self)(self.fget, self.fset, fdel, self.__doc__)
   ...:
```

Then:

```
In [6]: class Foo:
   ...:     @Property
   ...:     def bar(self):
   ...:         return 42
   ...:

In [7]: Foo.bar
obj is None in Property.__get__
Out[7]: <__main__.Property at 0x1044d02b0>


In [8]: Foo().bar
Out[8]: 42
```